# Fulfilment response PHP webhook not showing up in Actions on Google

Tags: php, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The fulfilment response is visible in diagnostic info in the Dialogflow environment. But it's not showing up when I test it in Actions on Google. Anyone who knows how to let it work? Here is my webhook code:

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == 'POST'){
        $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $json = json_decode($requestBody);

        $text = $json->queryResult->queryText;

        $date = (!empty($json->queryResult->parameters->date)) ? $json->queryResult->parameters->date : '';
        $environment  = (!empty($json->queryResult->parameters->environment)) ? $json->queryResult->parameters->environment : '';
        $intent   = (!empty($json->queryResult->intent->displayName)) ? $json->queryResult->intent->displayName : '';

        $responseText = prepareResponse($intent, $text, $date, $environment);

        $response = new \stdClass();
        $response->speech = $responseText;
        $response->displayText = $responseText;
        $response->source = "webhook";
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
        echo "Method not allowed";
}

function prepareResponse($intent, $text, $date, $environment)
    {
    return "You said: " . $text . " | I found Intent: " . $intent . " | with parameters: date=" . $date . " environment=" . $environment;    
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Responses for Actions on Google should be in an object under the `payload` attribute that contains a single attribute `google` with the [AoG response format](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body).

I haven't tested it, and this may not be the best way to build it, but something like the following should work:

```
$response->payload = array(
  "google" => array(
    "expectUserResponse" => TRUE,
    "richResponse" => array(
      "items" => array(
        array(
          "simpleResponse" => array(
            "textToSpeech" => $responseText
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: great! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it are always appreciated.